# 'rake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rake

Minutes ago, I downloaded the oscurrency code from github, and I'm installing oscurrency on heroku. Everything seemed to be going perfectly until this command: 
rake heroku:install
on the command line, in the directory where I downloaded the source code. I get the error:
'rake' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I'm following the installation instructions at heroku here:
https://github.com/oscurrency/oscurrency/wiki/Heroku-Deployment-Guide
The command "rake heroku:install" is in the third paragraph from the bottom.

The code I downloaded came in a top-level folder called oscurrency. I downloaded that onto my laptop in C:\me\oscurrency. I was issuing the command in that directory when I got the error. I tried issuing the command in the folder C:\me\oscurrency\oscurrency -- same error.

Maybe the command has changed for some reason. Anybody have an idea what's going wrong?

Comment: You're on Windows, right? Did you install Ruby/Rake using the default installer?

Comment: I think I'm missing Ruby/Rake.

Comment: Rake comes with Rails, if I'm not mistaken. Give this a shot: http://railsinstaller.org/en

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely that the command prompt is looking for a file named `rake.exe` and not able to find it because your `PATH` environment variable is not set to include that directory. I suspect that the `rails` command won't work either. You should add the ruby install directory (probably `C:\Program Files\Ruby on Rails\bin\` to your `PATH` environment variable.

To do this, open your Computer Properties by right-clicking My Computer and selecting Properties, then find the "Advanced System Settings" link. Click the "Environment Variables" button at the bottom, and paste the path to that directory into the PATH variable, separating it with a semicolon.

Comment: Bear with me, I'm feeling my way along.... I was strictly following the instructions at the link, which didn't explicitly mention that I had to specifically install Ruby or Rails. I think I assumed it was part of the installation I was doing. Apparently not. At this link: https://github.com/oscurrency/oscurrency I see: ruby 1.9.3 and
rails 3.2.16. So, where do I get those? I've done programming in C++ and PHP, and I've read about Ruby, so I think I get what Ruby is, but what is Rails? Should I be downloading 'Ruby on Rails'?

Comment: That seems to indicate that you need an older version of Ruby. Try https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-2.2.5.exe

Comment: Running this program should get you Ruby 1.9.3 with Rails 4.1, which is later than you want but *may* be compatible. If Rails 4.1 isn't backwards-compatible with 3.2, then you might have to install 3.2 manually.

Comment: Once you have Ruby and Rails installed, then `rake` should work as expected.

Comment: The installation seems to have worked. Now when I issue the command rake heroku:install, I get this error: <-[31mYour Ruby version is 1.9.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.5<-[0m   I installed the version stated at this link: https://github.com/oscurrency/oscurrency   So, where would be the best place to get Ruby 2.1.5? If I download the zip file at this link https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/11/13/ruby-2-1-5-is-released/   would that (possibly) work?

Comment: Well, that's a problem on the part of the people who are maintaining the oscurrency git repository. They should update their README. https://s3.amazonaws.com/railsinstaller/Windows/railsinstaller-3.1.0.exe is probably the one you wanted instead.

Comment: I installed it, ran it, issued command rake heroku:install and this is the output: http://www.screencast.com/t/x2m9JPHlp2  According to the instructions at this link: https://github.com/oscurrency/oscurrency/wiki/Heroku-Deployment-Guide  I'm supposed to be prompted for my Heroku API key, and then my Amazon credentials (if I didn't add them to the config file, which I didn't), but that isn't happening. I went to my dashboard at Heroku and clicked on applications, and there are no applications (should there be?). What am I missing?